# Pass jquery selector to function

Tags: jquery

Hello this may be an easy stupid question but how do i pass a jquery selector to a function?

Im doing this but its not working. Thanks in advance!

```
var $list=$('#startlist')
var $container=$list.parent();
var $containerTop=$('#toprow');
var $containerTwo=$('#etrow #bottomrow');

var $li=$list.find('li');

var totHt=0;
var totItems=$li.length;
var listCount = 0;
    $li.each(function( idx){

    var ht=$(this).outerHeight(true);

    if( totHt + ht >= maxHt || totHt + ht + 10 >=maxHt || idx==totItems-1){
        if (listCount>=3 && listCount < 6)
            createNewList($containerTop);
        else if (listCount >=6)
            createNewList($containerTwo);
        else
            createNewList($container);
        totHt=0;
        listCount++;
    }else{
        totHt += ht;
    }

});

function createNewList ($cont)
{
    $('<ul>').append( $(this).prevAll().andSelf() ).appendTo( $cont );

}
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

If i replace the if block with this it works fine:

```
if (listCount>=3 && listCount < 6)
                    $('<ul>').append( $(this).prevAll().andSelf() ).appendTo( $containerTop);
        else if (listCount >=6)
             $('<ul>').append( $(this).prevAll().andSelf() ).appendTo($containerTwo);
                else
             $('<ul>').append( $(this).prevAll().andSelf() ).appendTo($container);
```

Comment: Are you sure your elements exist when executing `$li.each...` ?

Comment: The function and passing a function looks fine, what is your code doing or not doing that is a problem?

Comment: Yes that is working fine. I just added that function. prior to that it was working fine but i wanted to make it a function instead of writing the append 3 times

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are defining your function outside of the `.each`, it is losing the context. Try using `.call` to properly set the context to what you expect it to be.

```
createNewList.call(this,$containerTop)
```

Comment: Wow your the man! thanks kevin. That worked. So can you explain further why i needed that?

Comment: Your function is outside of the $.each, so `this` in that context is probably the document. So you are saying $("<ul />").append(document) which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You can literally take `$("<ul>").append(document)` and place it in your console to get the same error.